# AJAX fails with a 404....but works anyway? What gives?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, model-view-controller

Maybe I should just keep my mouth shut and move forward, but something tells me things aren't working as nicely as I think they are and I need to fix it.

Basically, I'm doing a simple AJAX call to tell the server what the user has selected:  an already existing project or a new project.  The AJAX looks like this:

```
var dataString = 'existingProject='+ $("#existingProject").val() + '&newProjName=' + $("#newProjName").val();

//AJAX call to post selections to server
$.post('/myproj/manageProjects.html',dataString);
```

The Spring MVC signature that handles this post call looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/manageProjects",produces="application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public StatusResponse manageProjects(
        @RequestParam(value="existingProject",required=false) String existingProj,
        @RequestParam(value="newProjName",required=false) String newProj,
        HttpSession session){
```

What's blowing my mind is, I am getting the call into manageProjects with the correct variables and values I expect.  The server handles the request and returns a pojo I created called StatusResponse wrapping a boolean (success or failure) and a list of server feedback messages.  I create one with the simple status of "true" for success and pass it back.

The client then throws up a 404 manageProjects.html not found and continues on its merry way as though nothing has gone wrong.

So....did it find it or not?  If a StatusResponse-type pojo is an inappropriate response from a Spring MVC controller, what IS the right response?  Why would the message successfully hit the controller but then the client receive a 404?!

Thanks for any insight....

Footnote:  apologies if this looks similar to an earlier question from today.  I came at the core problem from the wrong angle and created more confusion than necessary in that posting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When this has happened to me, it's usually because there is a form in the dom, and you click a submit that fires an xhr.  It fires the xhr, but it also submits the form, which will default to the current url if none is supplied.  So try stopping the javascript event from propagating, removing the submit, or just remove the form tag.

Comment: A great suggestion.  I've run into this garbage before and solved it then by doing <form onsubmit="return false">.  In this case, I tried that and removing the form altogether with no luck.  

Same result: 404 from server "manageProjects.html" not found while still working perfectly.  I can't find another form that might be submitting it.  It's coming off a dialog so it's just one div.  Any other ideas?  Kinda stumped...

Comment: Actually...no.  I'm new to this kind of coding...can you elaborate on "all that biz" ? :)

Comment: I'm fuzzy on whether you mean programmatically or during testing.  I am not doing any kind of housecleaning in code, but I have tested across 3 browsers and seen the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding @ResponseBody annotation, somth like that

```
@RequestMapping(value="/deleteUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: Yep, it was caused by the lack of a ResponseBody.  Basically, the server sent back a response to the client that the client didn't understand.  This was throwing me because I assumed the 404 meant the URL I'd mapped wasn't found.